# Prove $\angle1\cong\angle4$

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I tried to complete this two-column proof with reasons per statement. Here's my work:

[image]

If someone could tell me where I went wrong, it would be very helpful.

Comment: What do you mean where you went wrong?  Why do you think you went wrong?

Comment: @fleablood I am not sure whether I need to use def. of rt. angles or def. of complementary angles.

Comment: Is seven steps really needed for $x+y = z+w$, $x = w$, therefore $y = z$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog The 7 steps are already stated and I just needed to complete the proof by providing the reasons for each step. and since this is a two-column proof, a proof for starters, my answer is yes.

Comment: Okay.... $\angle 3$ and $\angle 4$ are complimentary angles because the add to $\angle RST$ which is a right triangle.  That would be the definition of complimentary.  Frankly I'd knock of points for the text for not providing a step that states $\angle 1 + \angle 2 = \angle RST|$ visible by picture.

Comment: Seems OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

$\angle 1=90^\circ - \angle 2 = 90^\circ - \angle 3= \angle 4$